# Package equivalent for each distribution

Tags: linux, package, redhat

Sorry for this kinda noobish question but I would like to ask how can you determine a `package` equivalent for each distribution?

To better illustrate my case let me give you an example:

You can easily install the `apache package` on any distribution but when it comes to `RedHat` based OSs you face a different package : `httpd`.

I don't think this is the only case where this happens,so is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a global solution, but you can query each package manager, if you are looking for a file (like the apache executable).
E.g.:

- archlinux: pkgfile apache
- debian/ubuntu: apt-cache search apache